# Callback for jquery animation for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

As you can see at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/Pz5YB/23/), I animate more than one element at once,
which is happening as I wish. But in the next step, I would like to do things ONCE the animation for all elements is over. Which does not seem to be possible by using the complete-function, because it is it fired for EACH completed animation (3 elemets, 3 times complete callback). the jquery `.animate()` API also says:

> If multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

So, do you have any idea what I can do to have an event fired when every single animation has finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...animate(...).promise().done(function(){console.log("animate complete!")})
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, utterly jQuery. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can view currently animated with:

```
$(':animated').length
```

and on complete callback:

```
if($(':animated').length==1)
     console.log('whoohoo ready');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5YB/25/

Comment: wow. i would not have come to this. I did not know about the :animated selector before. should be linked in .animate() article I think? definitely helped me around.

Answer (score 0):

There you go, just added a simple counter :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5YB/24/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and count each time the animation is finished. If it equals 3 (or whatever number you want), call another function. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/Pz5YB/23/)

```
function animateAll(){
if(flag) return;
flag = true;
 //$('.list-wrapper').scrollLeft(w); // not sure why you need this
 //$('.table-wrapper').scrollLeft(w); // or this
 $('.list-wrapper, .table-wrapper').animate({
     scrollLeft: 2*w,
   }, function(){
       countAni++;
       console.log('finish');
       if(countAni == 3) finishAni()
   }     
 );
 function finishAni(){
     alert('whoohoo ready');   
     flag = false;
 }
```

Comment: I need to initially position the elements, thats why I scrollLeft first of all...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was a little unclear to me at first how to handle unrelated elements. Eventually I arrived at this answer:

```
 $.when(
     $someElement.animate(...).promise(),
     $someOtherElement.animate(...).promise()
).done(function() {
    console.log("whoohoo ready");
});
```